# What program to use to make software applications with Python?

Tags: python

Just like how Microsoft Visual Studio is used to make software applications for Windows OS computers, what programs are used to develop software applications using Python?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called an Integrated Development Environment, abbreviated IDE. Eclipse and PyDev are popular IDEs for Python development.

http://pydev.org/

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse and NetBeans have integrated python support. Search for 'IDE python' on the web to find many others. (IDE stands for 'Integrated Development Environment', Visual Studio is an IDE).

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is better choice,You can get plugins but you need to have Interpretor for Python.
Visit http://pydev.org/

Comment: I've chosen to go with Eclipse, how do I add GUI to my programs?

Answer (score 0):

Vim is my choice but Emacs and Sublime are also very good.